# Is there a way to get pynput to work on CodeHS's python 3 console

Tags: python, python-3.x, keypress, keyevent, pynput

I have a program in Pycharm that uses pynput in order to detect when the user presses a key on their keyboard, giving different results depending on the key pressed. There are 2 threads: one infinitely printing text, and the other looking for key presses, stopping the loop once a specific key is pressed. It works fine in Pycharm, but when I tried moving it to CodeHS's Python 3 console it does not work. In a requirements.txt file, I have:
`pynput`

and in main.py I have:

```
import time
import threading

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener


def show(key):
    global isKeyPressed, ButtonPressed
    if key == Key.backspace:
        # Stop listener
        isKeyPressed = True
        ButtonPressed = "backspace"
        return False
    elif key == Key.down:
        print("down")
        pass


def keyListeningThingy():
    with Listener(on_press=show) as listener:
        listener.join()


def bruhLoop():
    while isKeyPressed == False:
        print("bruh")
        time.sleep(0.5)


# Collect all event until released

ButtonPressed = ""
isKeyPressed = False

stillGoing = True

while stillGoing:

  x = threading.Thread(target=bruhLoop)
  y = threading.Thread(target=keyListeningThingy)

  x.start()
  y.start()

  x.join()
  y.join()
  keepGoing = input("Keep going?: ")
  if keepGoing == "yes":
      isKeyPressed = False
  else:
    exit()
```

My program does not throw any errors, but it also does not do anything when I press the keys, thus looping forever. Is there something I am doing wrong? Is there any alternatives to achieve the same goal? Am I having this problem because of the way CodeHS works?
I am not really sure what steps to take next in order to fix this problem, and I need to finish it by Tuesday.